# Como hacer que un Hashmap pueda leer un fichero .txt y separar su clave del valor usando la propiedad split

Tags: java, archivo, split, hashmap

espero haber sido específico con el título, tengo un fichero de texto .txt con el siguiente formato:

```
palabra1 -> palabra2
palabra3 -> palabra4
palabra5 -> palabra6
```

Nótese el salto de línea que hay.
Mi pregunta es como puedo hacer que un HashMap pueda leer este formato y consiga separar los elementos que hay, es decir, `palabra1(clave) -> palabra2(valor)`

Lo estoy intentando con split, pero no sé plantearlo. ¿Alguna idea? De momento mi código es el siguiente. Un saludo.

```
 public class juegoMemorizar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);

        //Preparativos

        String palabrass[]=null;
        String linea="";
        FileReader lectura=null;
        BufferedReader buffer_lectura=null;

        Map <String, String>lista=new HashMap<>();
        try{
            lectura= new FileReader("src/palabras.txt");
            buffer_lectura= new BufferedReader(lectura);
            do{
                linea=buffer_lectura.readLine();
                if(linea!=null){
                    palabrass=linea.split("->");
                    
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < palabrass.length; i++) {
                    lista.put(palabrass[i], palabrass[i]);
                }
                
            }while(linea!=null);
            

        }
        //Controlando excepciones
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        finally{
            try {
                buffer_lectura.close();
                lectura.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());

            }
        }
```

Comment: lo incorrecto es recorrer palabras con un for. Tú sabes que dado el formato del documento, palabras siempre tendrá 2 elementos, por tanto puedes asumir que: `lista.put(palabrass[0], palabrass[1]);` debería funcionar

Comment: Síi. Correcto, no te miento si te digo que llevaba toda la tarde dándole vueltas y no sabía como ponerlo jaja. Muchas gracias.